# Mysterious `timestamp` property in Realm swift

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to write RealmObjects to the db and I am getting this property `incompatible type` error when I try to insert it. The problem is that it's saying that it can't persist the property `timestampe` even though this property does not exist in my RealmObject. Here's the realm object verbatim:

```
class TransferR: Object {
    @objc dynamic var from_stop_id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var to_stop_id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var transfer_type: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var min_transfer_time: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var transfer_id:String = ""
    required convenience init(from_stop_id: String = "", to_stop_id: String = "", transfer_type: String = "", min_transfer_time: String = "") {
        self.init()
        self.from_stop_id = from_stop_id
        self.to_stop_id = to_stop_id
        self.transfer_type = transfer_type
        self.min_transfer_time = min_transfer_time
        self.transfer_id = transfer_type + "_" + from_stop_id + "_" + to_stop_id
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "transfer_id"
    }

    override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["from_stop_id", "to_stop_id"]
    }
}
```

As you can see there aren't any exotic types nor is there a `timestamp` property. Any ideas?

EDIT ----------------
Here's the complete error print out:

```
2018-04-26 12:04:55.243453-0400 WheresMyTrain[37970:1417331] Parsing transfers.txt file.
2018-04-26 12:04:55.565504-0400 WheresMyTrain[37970:1417092] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't persist property 'timestamp' with incompatible type. Add to Object.ignoredProperties() class method to ignore.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010334712b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001029dbf41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Realm                               0x00000001016ef7eb -[RLMProperty initSwiftPropertyWithName:indexed:linkPropertyDescriptor:property:instance:] + 2523
    3   Realm                               0x00000001016cdeac +[RLMObjectSchema propertiesForClass:isSwift:] + 1996
    4   Realm                               0x00000001016cbd5d +[RLMObjectSchema schemaForObjectClass:] + 941
    5   Realm                               0x000000010183f20b _ZL16RLMRegisterClassP10objc_class + 299
    6   Realm                               0x000000010184056d __25+[RLMSchema sharedSchema]_block_invoke + 77
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001032cbd72 -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 226
    8   Realm                               0x0000000101840224 +[RLMSchema sharedSchema] + 1044
    9   Realm                               0x000000010181b04b +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:] + 5627
    10  RealmSwift                          0x00000001022293a2 _T0So8RLMRealmCABSo0A13ConfigurationC13configuration_tKcfCTO + 162
    11  RealmSwift                          0x000000010222921e _T010RealmSwift0A0CACyKcfc + 126
    12  RealmSwift                          0x0000000102229146 _T010RealmSwift0A0CACyKcfC + 54
    13  WheresMyTrain                       0x0000000100775435 _T013WheresMyTrain10GtfsParserC5realm10RealmSwift0G0Cfg + 325
    14  WheresMyTrain                       0x000000010077de78 _T013WheresMyTrain10GtfsParserC10parseTable33_4859CB298B2937F388A70DD051310579LLySS5table_10Foundation3URLV4fileAA12RowProcessorC2rptF + 2232
    15  WheresMyTrain                       0x000000010077ce54 _T013WheresMyTrain10GtfsParserC14createRealmObj33_4859CB298B2937F388A70DD051310579LLy10Foundation3URLV4file_SS5tabletF + 15300
    16  WheresMyTrain                       0x0000000100778488 _T013WheresMyTrain10GtfsParserC05parseD033_4859CB298B2937F388A70DD051310579LLy10Foundation3URLV3url_tF + 4936
    17  WheresMyTrain                       0x0000000100776e68 _T013WheresMyTrain10GtfsParserC022downloadAndParseLatestD0yyFy9Alamofire16DownloadResponseVy10Foundation4DataVGcfU_ + 440
    18  WheresMyTrain                       0x000000010077713c _T013WheresMyTrain10GtfsParserC022downloadAndParseLatestD0yyFy9Alamofire16DownloadResponseVy10Foundation4DataVGcfU_TA + 12
    19  Alamofire                           0x0000000100cb1696 _T09Alamofire16DownloadResponseVy10Foundation4DataVGIxx_AGIxi_TR + 246
    20  Alamofire                           0x0000000100cb1732 _T09Alamofire16DownloadResponseVy10Foundation4DataVGIxx_AGIxi_TRTA + 66
    21  Alamofire                           0x0000000100cb043d _T09Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_ + 1181
    22  Alamofire                           0x0000000100cb673e _T09Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_TA + 110
    23  Alamofire                           0x0000000100c642e9 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 41
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001084572f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010845833d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001084635f9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103309e39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001032ce462 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001032cd889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bb909c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    31  UIKit                               0x00000001044115d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    32  WheresMyTrain                       0x000000010064f5b7 main + 55
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001084d4d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2018-04-26 12:05:35.025148-0400 WheresMyTrain[37970:1419045] Version 3.5.0 of Realm is now available: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v3.5.0/CHANGELOG.md
```

There's no `timestamp` property in my whole project so I am not sure where's that coming from. Here's the code for inserting into the realm db:

```
while csv.next() != nil {
                let row = rp.process(csv: csv)
                realmObjects.append(row)
                if (realmObjects.count > 10000) {
                    try realm.write {
                        realm.add(row)
                    }
                    DDLogInfo("Committing /(realmObjects.count) to the \(table) table.")
                    realmObjects = Array<Object>()
                }
            }
```

I am not doing anything exotic with the db.

Comment: I think that you have modified this Realm Object or that there is a different Realm Object  that carries this value, Make sure you do this and  try migration realm database  add this func in `appdelegate` in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
https://iswift.org/playground?Tfxhpw&v=3

Comment: Please include the actual code you use to insert the objects and that causes the error. You should also include the full error message in your question.